# Can I use Media Monkey to subscribe to an iTunes podcast?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, mediamonkey

How can I use something like Media Monkey to subscribe to [this iTunes podcast](http://iTunes.Apple.com/podcast/above-beyond-trance-around/id286889904). Also, can this be done without downloading iTunes in the first place...?

Answer (score 1):

Having never used MediaMonkey, I don't have a definite answer to the question of if this can be done with out having to download iTunes in the first place. But, from what I could find, if you're all ready subscribed to the podcast on iTunes, then...

> Use iTunes File -> Export and save the
>   OPML file.
>
> Use MM3 Edit -> Podcasts -> Add
>   Directory(OPML) to import the saved
>   file. This should create a new "iTunes
>   Subscribed Feeds" entry in the Podcast
>   Subscriptions -> Podcast Directories
>   tree node.

[Source](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Podcast_FAQ#How_do_I_export_an_OPML_directory_from_iTunes.3F)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [FeedFlipper](http://picklemonkey.net/feedflipper-home/) to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Feed mediamoneky with the Podcast RSS.

Go to the Podcast Website and copy the RSS link.

In this case I think it's enough to import the website Podcast itself.